# JQuery Div Does Not Refresh with New Content

Tags: jquery, html, refresh

The div #network-register needs to have it's contents replaced with new div with class reg-success-notification. The div content refreshes but the new content does not display or load.

```
$('#network-register').html('<div class="reg-success-notification"><p>Your account has been successfully created. You will be logged in within 5 seconds.</p></div>').fadeIn(1000);
        }

I found the issue was due to `"display: none"` in the CSS code of the div's class.


CSS Code

div.reg-success-notification {

   display:none
   ...more rules...
}
```

Comment: What is the role of that `}`? Can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: what is reg-success-notification css?

Comment: 1.Where are you using this code document ready() / onload  2. "reg-success-notification" css defined for this class

Comment: provide a demo on jsfiddle.net or provide a good code which explains ur scenario.. :-)

Comment: @SridharNarasimhan: You were right. It was a CSS rule display:none that was causing the problem. If you post your answer, I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Where are you using this code document ready() / onload                                    2. "reg-success-notification" css defined for this class

Thanks

Comment: I found that there was a display:none CSS rule that was causing the problem. This has been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

There are only a few reasons whey your code wouldn't work.

First Being that you misspelled something possibly the id="network-register".

Second would be that your code is executed at the wrong time.. Remember that if your code is called be for document.ready then the elements you are trying to use jQuery on will not be available in the DOM yet.

Easiest way thing to do is use your console in your developer tools to execute code and see what happens.. I personally use chrome.. Typing $("#network-register") in the console would be a quick and dirty check to see if it returns anything.. If you get back [] instead of [  then you know that your jQuery selector is silently failing and you either have a non existent element or you have a misspelling.

Quick tip for the future.. The more code and details you provide the better diagnosis to you problem you will get.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there was a `display:none` CSS rule that was causing the problem. This has been corrected.